# error while using PHP Outlook Web Access: Access Microsoft Exchange Web services via OWA API

Tags: php, outlook

I am using PHP Outlook Web Access: Access Microsoft Exchange Web services via OWA API for the sole purpose of accessing user's calendar appointment.Everything is working just fine for all user but for one specific user it's showing error as:

```
Message: Use of undefined constant _DEBUG_ - assumed '_DEBUG_'

Filename: classes/connection.php

Line Number: 51

There was a problem parsing your XML!

New http() object instantiated.

--------------------------------
fetch() called

url: https://exchange.icimod.org/Exchange/spandey/calendar/

getFromUrl() called
Authentication will be attempted

XML request will be sent

HTTP/1.1 302 Object Moved
Content-Length: 179
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://exchange-1.icimod.org/Exchange/spandey/calendar/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 05:12:21 GMT
Connection: close


    Object Moved

This document may be found here
New xml() object instantiated.

fetch() called.

XML error: Invalid document end at line 2

         Select * 
                FROM Scope('SHALLOW TRAVERSAL OF "/Exchange/spandey/calendar/"')
                WHERE NOT "urn:schemas:calendar:instancetype" = 1
                AND "DAV:contentclass" = 'urn:content-classes:appointment'

                ORDER BY "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart" ASC
```

In here link it gives the link of outlook express. Why is it so? Is it the problem of configuration or am I doing something wrong?

Any help/suggestion is welcome.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Guys found the problem area, Problem is user is stored in 2 seperate exchange account and I am using only one and not the other.

Comment: Hi @sammy I am trying to integrate PHP Outlook web access but getting 440 Login Timeout error. do you have any sample code just to authenticate the user ?? Please let me know